# Correlation Matrix Between Variables in R

Tags: r, correlation, panel-data

I have been trying to determine the correlation between variable in panel data. My data is in the form (with more dates, some values of PM10 are NA):

```
structure(list(NetC = c("Cosenza Provincia", "Cosenza Provincia", 
"Cosenza Provincia", "Cosenza Provincia", "Cosenza Provincia", 
"Cosenza Provincia", "Cosenza Provincia", "Cosenza Provincia", 
"Cosenza Provincia", "Reti Private", "Reti Private", "Reti Private", 
"Reti Private", "Reti Private", "Reti Private"), ID = c("IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT2086A", "IT2086A", "IT2086A", "IT2110A", 
"IT2110A", "IT2110A", "IT1766A", "IT1766A", "IT1766A", "IT2090A", 
"IT2090A", "IT2090A"), Stat = c("Citta dei Ragazzi", "Citta dei Ragazzi", 
"Citta dei Ragazzi", "Rende", "Rende", "Rende", "Acri", "Acri", 
"Acri", "Firmo", "Firmo", "Firmo", "Schiavonea", "Schiavonea", 
"Schiavonea"), Data = c("1/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "1/3/2022", "1/1/2022", 
"1/2/2022", "1/3/2022", "1/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "1/3/2022", "1/1/2022", 
"1/2/2022", "1/3/2022", "1/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "1/3/2022"), 
    PM10 = c(13.29, 11.14, 9.08, 16.62, 12.98, 10.4, 16.2, 19.4, 
    15.7, 10.82, 12.29, 9.54, 24.54, 22.88, 27.33)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

I have tried using `plm::cortab`, but it doesn't calculate the correlation.

```
library(plm)
cortab(data$PM10, grouping = Stat, groupnames = c("Citta dei Ragazzi", "Rende", 
                                                  "Acri", "Firmo", "Schiavonea"))
```

The output should look like:

|  | Citta dei Ragazzi | Rende | Acri |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Citta dei Ragazzi | 1 |  |  |
| Rende | x | 1 |  |
| Acri | x | x | 1 |

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to calculate a correlation between the date-ordered PM10 for each pair of 'Stat's? i.e. is Acri's PM10 from 1st, 2nd, and 3rd of Jan 2022 correlated with Rende's PM10 from 1st, 2nd, and 3rd of Jan 2022?

Comment: Yes, I want to see if PM10 concentrations between all sites presented a significant correlation.

Comment: Reshape long-to-wide then use cor, for example using data.table: `setDT(data); cor(dcast(data[, .(Stat, Data, PM10)], Data ~ Stat)[, -1])`

Comment: `Using 'PM10' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has pretty much already been asked ([How can I complete a correlation in R of one variable across it's factor levels, matching by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473889/how-can-i-complete-a-correlation-in-r-of-one-variable-across-its-factor-levels)) but for ease I have adapted that answer here for your use:

```
# simple correlation matrix:
data.wider <- data %>% 
  select(-ID, -NetC) %>% # remove unnecessary vars 
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'Stat', values_from = 'PM10')

cor(data.wider[,-1], use = 'p')  

# more lines required to set up correlation testing:
pw <- combn(unique(data$Stat),2) # make pairwise sets
pw

pairwise_c <- apply(pw,2,function(i){
  tidy(cor.test(data.wider[[i[1]]],data.wider[[i[2]]]))
})

results <- cbind(data.frame(t(pw)),bind_rows(pairwise_c))

results
```

Comment: Why you need to set up correlation testing?

Comment: In your comment before you mentioned checking for 'significant correlations', this requires correlation testing. It requires extra set up because each pairwise comparison has to be given to the 'cor.test' function individually...so it isn't as easy as feeding cor.test the full dataframe.